# Term for elements of a monoid in a corresponding monid ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, terminology, semigroups, monoid

What would be a proper term to use to call elements of a monoid $M$ in a corresponding [monoid ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_ring) $RM$ (where $R$ is a ring) or in a monoid algebra $kM$ (where $k$ is a field)?  Calling them *monomials* wouldn't be appropriate, or would it?

I am considering an ordered monoid $M$ and its monoid algebra $kM$, an I would like to talk about "monomial decomposition" of an element of $kM$, "the leading monomial" of an element of $kM$, etc.

Comment: Basis elements perhaps? In the context of group Hopf algebras, these are called "group-like elements", and the same definition would work for the monoid bialgebra.

Comment: I was hoping for something more self-explanatory than "leading basic element in the basic-element decomposition".

Answer (score 1):

I would reserve the use of *monomial* to the case of a [graded monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring#Graded_monoid), that is, a monoid equipped with a monoid morphism $d$ from $M$ into the additive monoid $\mathbb{N}$. This would allow one to define the *degree* of a monomial.

For instance if $M$ is the free monoid $A^*$, you obtain the ring of polynomials over the set of non-commutative variables $A$ and you can take as gradation $d$ the length of a word $u$.

Comment: Yeah, using elements of $M$ as degrees is a good choice too.

Comment: I do not think that some random (non-tivial) grading by $\mathbf{N}$ is what makes multivariate commutative monomials monomials.

Comment: While I have the chance: I have been trying to find biographical information on the algebraist Guy Renault, but I haven’t been having any luck searching in English. I donor know if he is even alive today. If you had a minute or two, (I think you must speak French) could you point me to some information on the web? I’d be happy to translate it on my own once I have it... thanks

Comment: @rschwieb, i've found that he had a student Maria Elisa Antunes Simoes: https://www.theses.fr/1987POIT2014.

Comment: @rschwieb I found another student: Annie Vogel Pavard [https://www.theses.fr/160284740](https://www.theses.fr/160284740) and I will try to know more about Guy Renault by other means. But it may take some time.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I appreciate the help you two have generated already! Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I think I may have located his dissertation, but I'm not sure: http://www.numdam.org/article/MSMF_1967__9__3_0.pdf .  Is "Thesè Sc. Math." an equivalent to a doctorate?

Comment: @rshwieb If I am not mistaken, this is a "thèse de science mathématique", a pre-1968 diploma, which was delivered after two years (to be compared to three years for a Ph.D. nowadays). See [Doctorat_en_France](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctorat_en_France) for an history.

Answer (score 0):

I would just call it the “leading order term”, taking care to define it using the monoid order.

When you write $\sum r_m m$ to denote an element of a semigroup ring, nobody refers to it as a “basic element decomposition.”  Everyone just takes it for granted that elements have this form. There doesn’t need to be a special word for the elements of $M$ in $kM$. Because we just refer to them as “elements of $M$” by identification.

I think it’s natural to call the term with the largest generator (with respect to the monoid order) the leading term. This fits completely with what we already do with the most famous monoid ring $\mathbb R[x]$.

The only reason we use “monomial” in polynomial rings is because we don’t introduce what a monoid is until much later (or never at all) so most people don’t have that framework to o think of them as  elements of a monoid.

Comment: I think, the leading *term* is $r_mm$ for the maximal $m$, not $m$ itself.

Comment: @Alexey What I mean is to say “let $m$ be the element of $M $ in the leading term.”  Or you can define elements of $M$ to be monomials if you want and refer to “the monomial of the leading term.” Sticking as much as possible to the analogy with polynomials makes the transaction more familiar.